# Power of sum algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

There is an algorithm question [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-power-sum/problem) about the sum of n-powers, I have tried to solve the problem using recursion which did not work before I checked the for the solution online and I got this:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = s.nextInt(), n = s.nextInt();
    int end = (int)Math.pow(x, 1.0/n);
    System.out.print(sumOfPower(x, n, end));

}


static int sumOfPower(int number, int power, int end) {
    int[] temp = new int[number + 1];
    temp[0] = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= end; i++) {
        int value = (int)Math.pow(i, power);
        for(int j = number; j > value - 1; j--) {
            temp[j] += temp[j-value];
        }

    }
    return temp[number];
}
```

I tried to study the code by logging the result at every loop, so the `sumOfPower` method now looks like this:

```
static int sumOfPower(int number, int power, int end) {
    int[] temp = new int[number + 1];
    temp[0] = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= end; i++) {
        int value = (int)Math.pow(i, power);
        for(int j = number; j > value - 1; j--) {
            System.out.println( "j:"+j+"\tj-value:"+(j-value)+ "\ttemp[j]:" + temp[j] + "\ttemp[j-value]:" + temp[j-value] );
            temp[j] += temp[j-value];
            System.out.println(i + ": " + Arrays.toString(temp));
        }

    }
    return temp[number];
}
```

I understand how the loop and dynamic programming logic work to some extent with the log I had using `x=10` and `n=2`. The log looks like:

```
10
2
j:10    j-value:9   temp[j]:0   temp[j-value]:0
1: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
j:9 j-value:8   temp[j]:0   temp[j-value]:0
1: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
j:8 j-value:7   temp[j]:0   temp[j-value]:0
1: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
j:7 j-value:6   temp[j]:0   temp[j-value]:0
1: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
j:6 j-value:5   temp[j]:0   temp[j-value]:0
1: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
j:5 j-value:4   temp[j]:0   temp[j-value]:0
1: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
j:4 j-value:3   temp[j]:0   temp[j-value]:0
1: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
j:3 j-value:2   temp[j]:0   temp[j-value]:0
1: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
j:2 j-value:1   temp[j]:0   temp[j-value]:0
1: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
j:1 j-value:0   temp[j]:0   temp[j-value]:1
1: [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
j:10    j-value:6   temp[j]:0   temp[j-value]:0
2: [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
j:9 j-value:5   temp[j]:0   temp[j-value]:0
2: [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
j:8 j-value:4   temp[j]:0   temp[j-value]:0
2: [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
j:7 j-value:3   temp[j]:0   temp[j-value]:0
2: [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
j:6 j-value:2   temp[j]:0   temp[j-value]:0
2: [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
j:5 j-value:1   temp[j]:0   temp[j-value]:1
2: [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
j:4 j-value:0   temp[j]:0   temp[j-value]:1
2: [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
j:10    j-value:1   temp[j]:0   temp[j-value]:1
3: [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
j:9 j-value:0   temp[j]:0   temp[j-value]:1
3: [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

What I need to know currently is the mathematical logic behind this, how do I know that after the looping that `temp['number']` is the total possible number of ways `x` can be expressed as the sum of the `nth`  powers of unique natural numbers. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let start with an abstract model of the problem, giving a DAG [directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), how many ways to travel from one node to other node?

Let call the function to answer this question is `f(start, end)`

we can easily see that

```
f(start, end) = sum f(x , end) with x are the neighbours of start
```

and for the base case `f(end, end) = 1` (there is one way to travel from end to end, as this graph has no cycle). And, as this is a DAG, so the above function will converge.

Similarly, you can see that the same model can be applied to this problem.

Let say we need to calculate `f(X, 0)` with X is the initial value, we can see that from value X, we can reach to all value `X - y`, with `y` is the Nth power number.

So

```
f(X, 0) = sum f(X - y, 0) with y is all Nth power number less than or equal X

f(0,0) = 1
```

In the code you have given, `temp` is storing the answer for `f` from `f(0, 0) to f(value, 0)`.

So, why this is a DAG? because the value of Nth power are positive, so no way we can go back to a previous state.

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me with recursion. Simply be careful with the limits (start, end, and target sum):

```
public class powerSum {
    static int solutions = 0;

    static void process(int currentSum, int targetSum, int currentNumber, int n) {
    if (currentSum == targetSum) {
        solutions++;
        return;
    }

    for (int i = currentNumber; currentSum + (int) Math.pow(i, n) <= targetSum; i++)
        process(currentSum + (int) Math.pow(i, n), targetSum, i + 1, n);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        process(0, 100, 1, 2);
        System.out.println(solutions);
    }

}
```

**Solutions = 3**